# Login script using EmailSignature.NewMessageSignature property does not populate in Outlook

Tags: outlook, vbscript

I have been experimenting with this object.property in a logon script and have the following snippit of code.  It does not seem to populate in Outlook in the default signatures.  Has anyone had any luck with this?  I am using MS Office 2016

```
    ...
    SigFilename = "CompanyDefault.htm"
    ...
    'Applying the signature in Outlook’s settings.
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objSignatureObjects = objWord.EmailOptions.EmailSignature
    
    'Setting the signature as default for new messages.
    objSignatureObjects.NewMessageSignature = SigFilename
    
    'Setting the signature as default for replies & forwards.
    objSignatureObjects.ReplyMessageSignature = SigFilename
    objWord.Quit
```

Comment: It could be that the file can't be found. Have you tried with a full path to the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `NewMessageSignature` and `ReplyMessageSignature` take the name of the signature (e.g. `"CompanyDefault"`), not the file name (`"CompanyDefault.htm"`).

If you want to manipulate Outlook signatures directly, you can do so using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) - it exposes the [RDOSession](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`Signatures` collection (returns [RDOSignatures](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOSignatures.htm) object),  as well as [RDOAccount](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAccount.htm).`ReplySignature` and `NewMessageSignature` properties (retuirn and take [RDOSignature](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOSignature.htm) object).

Comment: Excellent - this is why this site is so helpful.  The debugging didn't throw an exception and I needed a hint.  Thank you Dmitry

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you assigned a logon script to a local user account.

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article.

I'd suggest making sure the code works correctly when it is run manually. If not, try to run the code under the debugger to find out what is wrong and where it fails. At least you can add logging statements.

Comment: Thank you for the caveat.  This problem is presenting itself when I run it as myself under a local user account before attaching it to a logon script.  The code is not working and I cannot find why it will not - hence the reason why I posted it here.